# @RequestMapping annotation isn't display while using Press 'Ctrl+Space'.No completions available.I worked on STS-3 IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[LocationController.java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZy52.png)

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuF4g.png)

Comment: Please provide better explanation and insert image in the question.

Comment: It seems there is an exception in pom.xml  
https://start.spring.io/ use this and build it again

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your jars are not downloaded or not in build path(Maven dependencies jar in eclipse) check all of spring boot jars are downloaded and these jars are in build path.Right click on project update your maven project select offline and force update option checkbox. and also check

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```